# How to know when a UserControl is no longer used (no Close event)

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

I'm using `UserControl`s inside a `WinForm` to display data.
I'm also using the command pattern so that the `UserControl` registers a (weak) event and does stuff when the command is triggered.

On a `WinForm` I can unregister the events in the `Close` event. However there's no such event on a `UserControl`.
I hooked up the events I thought would be fired when the `UserControl` is no longer in the display stack but could find nothing useful.
To get by I check if the `Parent` is null and that worked for most of the cases.

Now I'd like to have a child `UserControl` of another `UserControl` (put the `UserControl` inside a `TabControl`) and the `Parent` property isn't going to be null for the child control anymore when the parent is no longer displayed.

Is there any way to know if the `UserControl` is used?

What I've tried so far: `Dispose()` doesn't get called straight away by the system so it's no useful; `IsVisible` doesn't get updated by the system either; there is no `Close` or `Unload` event fired.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is the Dispose() method.  If it doesn't get called early enough then there's a bug in the code that uses the control.  Using Controls.Clear() or Controls.Remove() for example.

The parent of a control always iterates its Controls collection and disposes the child controls when it gets disposed.  Which makes disposing automatic, starting at the form's Dispose() which runs when the form is closed.  It is however *not* automatic when you remove controls yourself.

Comment: I'm doing the adding and removing of the UserControl myself. There's no Disposed event and the Dispose method is already overridden in the designer code so there's no hook for me to put my own code there.

Comment: Cut and paste the Dispose method override from the Designer.cs file to your code file.  One of the few valid edits of a designer file, it is *before* the region marked "Component Designer generated code".

Comment: I didn't know it was acceptable to put the Dispose() method in the main class file. That looks like the right way to go then. It doesn't solve my issue with 2 controls in a tab and checking if the current control is active or not but I think I'll have to code that myself.

Answer (score 3):

There is a HandleDestroyed event on the Control that might work for you.

Comment: Yeah, but be careful with it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657862/handledestroyed-event-in-usercontrol).

Answer (score 0):

In the past I dealt with this problem by getting the parent form (using Control.ParentForm) and then hooking up to the FormClosing event directly.

The tricky part is knowing when to call ParentForm.  It's not set when the user control is first created.  Sometimes I override the OnLayout handler and monitor until the ParentForm is not null.